# Singleton Service properties not updated .net core 2 razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

When my page loads i fire 2  unobtrusive Jquery requests using the asp.net helpers as seen below

```
    <div id="stdReplace">
                        <form method="get" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-url="/Stats/Index/QuickChart"
                              data-ajax-failure="PulseTs.HttpUtilsTs.httpRequestFailed"
                              data-ajax-success="stdOnComplete"
                              data-ajax-method="get"
                              data-ajax-begin="PulseTs.VisualHelpersTs.blockElement(stdReplace)"
                              data-ajax-update="#stdReplace"
                              data-ajax-mode="REPLACE-WITH"
                              class="quickChartForm">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="std"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Which both reach the correct handler and return a partial view to update the parent element they rest in
The handler:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetQuickChart(string id)
        {
            await _serviceStats.GetGeneralStats(routeName, startDate, endDate);
            string key = "ssts" + id.First().ToString().ToUpper() + id.Substring(1);


            if (string.Equals(id, "avg"))
            {
                TempData["ChartTitle"] = "avg";
                TempData["ChartId"] = "avgChart";


            }
            else
            {

                TempData["ChartTitle"] = "std";
                TempData["ChartId"] = "stdChart";
            }
            return new PartialViewResult
            {
                StatusCode = 200,
                ViewName = "Stats/Partial/_QuickChartView",
                ViewData = ViewData,
                TempData = TempData
            };
```

Now get GetGeneralTtats function should internally update one of the services properties, which when i debug it does. But i also inject this service into my Razor Page View and when i attempt to retrieve that property in javascript it is empty

i inject the service in the razor page as such

```
@inject IServiceStats ServiceStats
```

and attempt to retreive the property in js as below

```
data = @Json.Serialize(ServiceStats.StatsVm.AvgData);
```

When debugging i see this

[image]

But when i console.log(data)

i get this

[image]

Why is the property of the singleton service not updated shouldn't it be the same throughout the lifetime of the application?

Comment: The property of the instance is update, but your JS doesn't have that instance. It has a copy of it, and that copy is an older state, where properties haven't been populated

Comment: Shouldn't the razor view hold a copy to the reference of that object and thus any update on that happen on that object as well? If not do you know how i can achieve that so it can reflect those updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got parts of this happening on the server and parts happening on the client. When your model is provided to the view, and then later set as the value of `data` in your JS, that's all happening server-side. The `data` variable doesn't actually even exist, it's just text for all the server is concerned. The serialized value of your model is simply being dumped to the page in that spot. Then, after the response is returned, and the browser (the client) runs the JS on the page, then and only then is `data` set to something, which is just a JS object at that point.

When you make a request via AJAX, you're able to affect the model on the server, but this has *zero* impact on what's already been done client-side. If you need to the updated data, you would need to make a request specifically for that to the server, return that data as the response from the server (JSON), and then set the `data` JS variable with that JSON response.

Comment: Thank you i suspected as much but having a confirmation allows me to stop trying in such a way and doing it the way you suggested.